# Custom authentication with ADFS(Not multifactor)

Tags: asp.net, authentication, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs3.0

I need a good advise and wanted to know whether a solution is feasible or not. Right now one of my customer has a common login application which is based on Forms authentication(ASP.NET) using membership provider. All internal users use their AD credentials to logon and external users use custom username and password. Both are wrapped via Forms authentication. Now the new proposal is to replace this Forms authentication with ADFS. I have gone through various articles over internet and not able to come to a conclusion. Let me list my findings so far with ADFS extension points.

1) It is possible to add a custom attribute to ADFS claims by the approach mentioned in https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudpfe/2013/12/27/how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-store-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0/.

2) It is possible to add a second level of authentication( or multifactor authentication) via the approach https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jenfieldmsft/2014/03/24/build-your-own-external-authentication-provider-for-ad-fs-in-windows-server-2012-r2-walk-through-part-1/. Here I understand that after first level authentication done by AD then only our external provider will come into picture.

So I have a general question that is it really possible to achieve what I am looking for with ADFS. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on where the user accounts are stored. If both internal and external users are in AD, you can just redirect to ADFS.

If internal is in AD and external is in an untrusted or other LDAP source, using ADFS 2016 you can link to both these account stores and still offload authentication to ADFS.

If external is in SQL, you can either use a virtual directory in front to project it as an LDAP store (previous option) or use IdentityServer.

If externs is something else, you'd need IdentityServer.

Thanks //Sam (@MrADFS)

Comment: Hello Sam, Thanks for your reply. In my case, internal users are in AD and external are in ADLDS. Unfortunately client is using Windows Server 2008R2(only ADFS2.0 is available). Can ADFS work with multiple stores (AD and ADLDS in my case). I saw this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/102944e3-716e-447b-b2c8-151dd636cd49/using-two-user-stores-for-one-relying-party-trust?forum=Geneva. Could you please suggest some solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can add a custom attribute store.

Yes - you can add a custom authenticator.

A better way might be to use thinktecture's IdentityServer 3.0 for the ASP.NET Identity part and then federate IdentityServer and ADFS.